# Is it valid to use the `not` keyword for conditional dependency in Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is it valid syntax to use the `cfg(not(...))` in a Cargo.toml for declaring dependencies?

```
[target.'cfg(not(target_arch = "wasm32"))'.dependencies]
websocket = "0.23.0"

[target.'cfg(target_arch = "wasm32")'.dependencies.web-sys]
version = "0.3.22"
features = [
  "ErrorEvent",
  "MessageEvent",
  "WebSocket",
]
```

I get the error `can't find crate "websocket"` for the following code:

```
macro_rules! if_not_wasm {
    ($($i:item)*) => ($(
        #[cfg(not(target_arch = "wasm"))] $i
    )*)
}

macro_rules! if_wasm {
    ($($i:item)*) => ($(
        #[cfg(target_arch = "wasm")] $i
    )*)
}

if_not_wasm! {
    extern crate websocket;
}

if_wasm! {
    extern crate web_sys;
}
```

The import in `if_wasm!` works as expected but the `if_not_wasm!` errors. I'm running this with the following `.cargo/config`:

```
[build]
target = "wasm32-unknown-unknown"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need `wasm32`, not `wasm`, in your macro rules condition.